# How to pass form data from child component to parent component

Tags: reactjs, parent-child, child-process

I want to send the form data which is in my child to parent component. On 
  submit function I have written in Parent component.
  Parent Component :

```
    handleChangeValue = (e) => {
      this.setState({
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
        [e.target.value]: e.target.value
     });
   }

   handleSubmit() {
      var newObj = {
      'id' : this.state.id,
      'name' : this.state.name,
   };

   render() {
     return (
       <div className="App">
        <UsingForm onChangeValue = 
         {this.handleChangeValue} handleSubmit = {this.handleSubmit}> 
         </UsingForm>
      </div>
     );
   }
```

And Child component is:

```
 <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
     <label>
      Name:
        <input type="text" name="uname" value = {this.props.uname} 
        onChange={(e)=>this.props.onChangeValue(e)}></input>
     </label>
     <label>
     ID:
      <input type="text" name="id" value = {this.props.id} onChange= 
       {(e)=>this.props.onChangeValue(e)}></input>
      </label>
      <input type="button" value="Submit" onClick= 
      {this.props.handleSubmit} />
 </form>
```

Not getting state values in `handleSubmit()`, why?

Comment: Bind handleSubmit function or use arrow expression, pass uname and id props, also initialize them before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to bind `handleSubmit` function using arrow function

```
handleSubmit = () => {
      var newObj = {
      'id' : this.state.id,
      'name' : this.state.name,
      };
```

or in constructor

```
constructor(props) {
  ...
  this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did that. Now It gives me this error : "TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined handleSubmit" in my handleSubmit().

 handleSubmit() {
         var newObj = {
         'id' : this.state.id,
         'name' : this.state.name,
         };
         console.log(newObj);

Comment: There is no `handleSubmit` method in your child component. Please remove `onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}` from your `<form>` tag in child component

Answer (score 0):

You have to change

```
<label>
  Name:
    <input type="text" name="name" value = {this.props.name} 
    onChange={(e)=>this.props.onChangeValue(e)}></input>
 </label>
```

and

```
<UsingForm onChangeValue = 
     {this.handleChangeValue} handleSubmit = {this.handleSubmit} name={this.state.name} id={this.state.id}> 
</UsingForm>
```